# How to store 'blob' type in MySQL with Entity Framework Core using byte[]?

Tags: mysql, entity-framework-core

I have code first model that looks like this:

```
public class Document
{
    [Key]   
    public int DocumentId {get;set;}

    [Required]
    public byte[] Blob {get; set;}
}
```

I want that to map to blob data type in MySQL but I keep getting varbinary(255)

How do I get it to map to "blob"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used [Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql](https://github.com/PomeloFoundation/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql) to fix my problem.

Comment: A workaround, if Pomelo is not an option, is to use the `text` type to store binary data.

Answer (score 3):

In your OnModelCreating do:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Document>(entity =>
{
  entity.Property(x => x.Blob ).HasColumnType("blob");
}
```

Comment: Also the following attribute declaration can o the same:
[Column(TypeName = "blob")]