# .Net6.0 MySQL adding base64 to BLOB type always empty

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0, heidisql

I have a MVC project which i am using Entity Framework. In database i used MySQL with HeidiSQL. In table i have a column with a BLOB type. I want to store base64 url. I successfully add data but my BLOB type data is always empty.

My object:

```
public partial class Label
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string? OrderId { get; set; }
    public string? Title { get; set; }
    public string? Sku { get; set; }
    public byte[]? Image { get; set; }
    public string? MimeType { get; set; }
    public string? Status { get; set; }
}
```

My controller funnction:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult addInformation(string title,string orderId,string sku, List<string> shipmentInfoList)
{
    foreach(var shipment in shipmentInfoList)
    {
        string b64 = shipment.Split(",")[1];
        byte[] imageData = Convert.FromBase64String(b64);
        string mimetype = shipment.Split(";")[0].Split(":")[1];
        var label = new Label
        {
            Title = title,
            OrderId = orderId,
            Sku = sku,
            Image = imageData,
            MimeType = mimetype,
            Status = "Labeled"
        };

        _context.Labels.Add(label);
    }

    _context.SaveChanges();

    return Json(true);
}
```

When i try to get **FirstOrDefault** value its **Image** variable's count is 0 and in table when i view it it is empty.

My **context**, **OnModelCreating**:

```
    modelBuilder.Entity<Label>(entity =>
    {
        entity.ToTable("labels");

        entity.Property(e => e.Image).HasColumnType("blob");

        entity.Property(e => e.MimeType).HasMaxLength(50);

        entity.Property(e => e.OrderId).HasMaxLength(50);

        entity.Property(e => e.Sku)
            .HasMaxLength(50)
            .HasColumnName("SKU");

        entity.Property(e => e.Status).HasMaxLength(50);

        entity.Property(e => e.Title).HasMaxLength(250);
    });
```

Comment: Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41234762/how-to-store-blob-type-in-mysql-with-entity-framework-core-using-byte

Comment: For the record, you're not saving base64 anything. "BLOB" stands for "binary large object", so you're storing binary data. Base64 is a format for serialising binary data as text. The BLOB and the base64 are completely separate. As long as your call to `Convert.FromBase64String` is returning what you expect, the base64 text is irrelevant to the issue. The binary data could be coming from anywhere. If that call is not returning what you expect then the BLOB is irrelevant, because you don't have the correct data before saving.

Comment: What @jmcilhinney said. Set a breakpoint in `addinformation`and step through it. Is `shipmentInfoListe` what you expect? Is each `shipment` what you expect? This is clearly meant to be a delimited string of some sort, but you first split it on ",", then again on ";". This looks suspicious. Does each element returned from each split look as expected? Does `b64` look like a base-64 string?

Comment: The coding seems correct. Could there be an error in the `split` process? `imageData` might have received an empty value. Have you checked these?

Comment: @jmcilhinney it returns what i expect.

Comment: @Alparslan ŞEN split process is correct. Data i get is like this data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAetc. so with splitting i get base64 formatted image and on debug when i check its value and convert it to image on internet it gives true image.

Comment: @Petter Hesselberg everything looks fine.

Comment: In that case, the base64 stuff is irrelevant. One of the things you're supposed to do here is provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Your code is definitely not minimal because the splitting and base64 conversion are irrelevant to the issue. Reproducible is a bit more challenging, because you need to provide an EF context that we can use. It can be done though, if you're prepared to make the effort to create something that includes only what is required to demonstrate this issue.

Comment: Can you try making the byte array in the Label partial class not null? This way, if a null value is encountered, the application will crash, and you can see the error.

Comment: @AlparslanŞEN i tried it but it is not null or empty. It is empty in database.

Comment: @jmcilhinney i added my context to question.